# NameError in PagesController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancancan, rolify

I'm trying to create a login system with devise, cancancan and rolify. The devise part is working. I recently added cancancan and rolify and I'm trying to test if they are working.

My cancancan ability file:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)

    if user.has_role? :admin
      can [:index], Page
    else
      can [:index,:lecture]
    end
  end
end
```

I have a root page `root to: "pages#index"` which is working. If I add `load_and_authorize_resource` at the top of the pages controller like

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
  end

  def lecture
  end

end
```

I get back when trying to access it:

`NameError in PagesController#index` generate by these lines:

```
      names.inject(Object) do |constant, name|
    if constant == Object
    *  constant.const_get(name)
    else
      candidate = constant.const_get(name)
      next candidate if constant.const_defined?(name, false)
```

The * is the line that gives the error. I also saw in the rolify documentation that I have to add `resourcify` to the files that are going to make use of it. But if I try to add it I get an error `undefined method resourcify`.  How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

**GemFile:**

```
gem 'load_and_authorize_resource'
# bundle install after
```

**ApplicationController:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include LoadAndAuthorizeResource
end
```

**PagesController**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  ....
```

More Info here [Load And Authorize Resource](https://github.com/seven1m/load_and_authorize_resource)

Comment: I will check that soon, but I don;t think that i have to install a gem for that. I've used cancancan a week ago(it was working, but I had my own user system with sessions, not devise) and I know that I haven't loaded a new gem for that method.